# Convert python script outputs to pdf just like jupyter notebook

Tags: python, pandas, pdf, jupyter-notebook

I have been looking for something similar to this:

```
!jupyter nbconvert File.ipynb --no-input --to pdf
```

It's just that I cant use jupyter in the production environment, So i have to convert it into script and then generate pdf using that script.
Also, input should not be displayed in the pdf file, Just the outputs.
Do we have something like this in normal python?

I have N number of lines written in jupyter and I want the output from those lines of code to be in a pdf. Like a report

Comment: You could have a look at [Code2pdf](https://pypi.org/project/Code2pdf/).

Comment: @AnoopRDesai Thanks but it does not  have any option to disallow inputs in pdf

Comment: I don't want to include inputs in the pdf

Comment: you can use `logger` with logging file as `.pdf` https://docs.python.org/2.6/library/logging.html

Comment: @MohamedThasinah It also does not have any option to not allow inputs to be displayed in pdf

Comment: I didn't get you clearly, logger is a file, if you don't want to include some contents then don't add into your logger object.

Comment: So my goal is generate a pdf out of my python script but the pdf should contain only the outputs and not the code(inputs), okay?

Comment: Yeah man, logger is just like print statement. If you want to save the particular content use logger statement or else leave it. don't get confuse with input and output.